# Why my checkbox on change is not working on js file, but working on console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to get the selected checkbox text when on change.

Here is my aspx code

```
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
    <li class="">
        <a tabindex="0">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1001"> 1001</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a tabindex="0">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1111"> 1111</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a tabindex="0">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="2222"> 2222</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a tabindex="0">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="3333"> 3333</label>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Jquery code what tried

```
$('.multiselect-container :checkbox').change(function () {
    $('.multiselect-container input:checkbox').each(function () {
        var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
        alert(sThisVal);
    });
    alert('working');
});
```

**Note**

> When I run on `js` file, it doesn't show the alert. but when i tried on console. it is working...

```
Can you tell me answer with reason why it is not working with js file?
```

Comment: probably you call it before page load complete

Comment: wrap code inside jquery ready function check console for any errors

Comment: @FastSnail I run it already inside the ready function. My other jquery functions are running except this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the js code after the page is loaded. There are many ways:

1. Put the script tag at the end of the body:
2. Wrap your script with a function a call it after the page is loaded. This can be done either by adding the onload attribute on the body (more at [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)) or by adding a script tag at the end of the body that only calls the function.
3. You can use the jQuery `ready` or `on load` (more at [jQuery doc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/))

Comment: how to get only selected checkbox in if condition ` if ($(this.checked).is(':checked')) { }` like this?

Comment: `$(this).is(":checked")`